# How to run csvsql in windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, csvkit

I am able to install [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.3/index.html), however, how to use that in Windows? I believe there are really barely people using it in Windows as my search doesn't give me a useful hint.

It doesn't start in command line, nor in python shell. I remember I used it in terminal directly in CentOS, correct me if I am wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I installed it with pip in python35 in windows 7